# Is there a way to find out what font Firefox is using?

Tags: firefox, fonts

I've got some truly horrible font (or fonts) installed on my system, and Firefox is choosing to use them sometimes.

Now, that's not Firefox's fault for finding these fonts, but I'd like to figure out what they are, so I can uninstall them.

Is there a way to find out, in Firefox, what font it's using for a particular character on the screen?

Answer (score 2):

Font Finder Firefox add on saves your time  in this  issue
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4415/

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Tools** -> **Options** -> **Content** tab -> **Font and Colors** section. You will find out what type of font Firefox is using there.

-Hope this helps!

Comment: That's what fonts I'm *suggesting* that it uses, but webpages are obviously using a lot of fonts not listed there ("Allow pages to choose their own...").  For example, Japanese pages are using at least 3 or 4 different fonts (katakana and hiragana seem to be different fonts, and it looks like it's pulling kanji glyphs from at least 2 different fonts, too), and how would I set kana and kanji fonts, anyway?  It only has popups for "Proportional", "Serif", "Sans-serif", and "Monospace", and none of those sound like they apply to non-Latin characters at all.

Answer (score 0):

This [addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/80830/) for firefox might solve your issue, it allows you to switch fonts